# Git clone on WSL gives "permission denied" error [WSL1]

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm currently using *WSL* as my development environment for a work project. When running an `npm install` on a company project, I receive this error:

```
Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone -q <redacted url> /home/ambrose/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-393358b0
/home/ambrose/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-393358b0/.git: Permission denied
```

However, if I create the folder manually using `mkdir`, the install proceeds until it hits another folder that it cannot create.

The *IntelliJ* project is on my *Windows* hard drive (`/mnt/d/...`), if that makes any difference.

My question is: how can I avoid having to create every folder by hand during this `npm install`, and what seems to be the underlying problem?

Comment: Just got to check the obvious before looking at this in more detail but I assume you are using wsl to do the npm install and not the cmd prompt from inside intelij?

Comment: @Damo: Yes, I did use npm to install.

Comment: Can you give a list of all the commands inside the wsl prompt that you are running  
for example:  
  
`cd /mnt/c/code  
git clone ssh://git@...../myproject.git  
npm install`  
  
Also are you using nvm?  
What version of node and npm are you using?  
Also what is the output from `ls -l ~/.npm` what are the permissions and ownership for this folder?  
Also what happens if you clone a public repo and try to npm install that. In other words is this issue particular to your companies repo?

Answer (score 5):

What I discovered is that WSL was incorrectly handling file locking and file access. My editor was accessing the directory at the same time as NPM, which was causing locking errors.

While I no longer use WSL on a daily basis for work, this issue seems to have been resolved with more recent updates to WSL. If the issue crops up again, the way I fixed the issue was:

- close the file or folder in question within the editor and rerun the command.
- If the issue persists, close the editor and rerun the command.

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: I had the same problem when windows explorer was open